# Why can a *S Slice be initialed by literal S?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I saw this syntax in page187 of [the go programming language](http://www.gopl.io/).

```
var tracks = []*Track{
    {"Go", "Delilah", "From the Roots Up", 2012, length("3m38s")},
    {"Go", "Moby", "Moby", 1992, length("3m37s")},
    {"Go Ahead", "Alicia Keys", "As I Am", 2007, length("4m36s")},
    {"Ready 2 Go", "Martin Solveig", "Smash", 2011, length("4m24s")},
}
```

Is it just a syntax sugar of

```
var tracks = []*Track{
    &Track{"Go", "Delilah", "From the Roots Up", 2012, length("3m38s")},
    &Track{"Go", "Moby", "Moby", 1992, length("3m37s")},
    &Track{"Go Ahead", "Alicia Keys", "As I Am", 2007, length("4m36s")},
    &Track{"Ready 2 Go", "Martin Solveig", "Smash", 2011, length("4m24s")},
}
```

I haven't googled the specification of it, please give me the link if there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ref spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)

> Within a composite literal of array, slice, or map type T, elements or map keys that are themselves composite literals may elide the respective literal type if it is identical to the element or key type of T. Similarly, elements or keys that are addresses of composite literals may elide the &T when the element or key type is *T.

```
[...]*Point{{1.5, -3.5}, {0, 0}}    // same as [...]*Point{&Point{1.5, -3.5}, &Point{0, 0}}
```